# Audio streaming from URL failed to init from data source?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I'm trying to get the stream from the URL but I keep getting **Failed to init from data source** error

Here's my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val url = "http://www.radioideal.net:8026/;stream/1"

    try {
        val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer().apply {
            setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            setDataSource(url)
            prepareAsync()
            start()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.message
    }

}
```

It's the simplest example.

Answer (score 1):

Your are calling start right after prepareAsync() which might be casuing problem. Please use the code below

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     val url = "http://www.radioideal.net:8026/;stream/1"

        try {
            val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer().apply {
                setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                setDataSource(url)
                setOnPreparedListener(this@MainActivity)
                prepareAsync()

            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }


    }


    override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        mp?.start()
    }
```

And donot forgot to implement MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.... Cheers

Comment: how do you implement the OnPreparedListener?

Comment: class myclass:MediaPlayer:OnPreparedListener{

    override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        mp?.start()
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    play_btn.setOnClickListener {
        val mp = MediaPlayer ()
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this@MainActivity)
        try {
            mp.setDataSource ("https://www.ssaurel.com/tmp/mymusic.mp3")
            mp.prepareAsync ()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
        }
            Toast.makeText (this, "Wait a moment while loading the mp3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ()
        }
    }

    override fun onPrepared (p0: MediaPlayer?) {
       p0?.start()
    }
}
```